# Rigorous justification of some steps in evaluating limit of integrals using Hôpital's rule

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

I have a doubt if I am evaluating a limit of integral rigorously.

Suppose that we have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and assume we want to evaluate
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{x^2} f(t)dt$$

It is easy, using Hôpital's rule, to show that the limit is $0$ because, writing the function as $\frac{\int_0^{x^2}f(t)dt}{x}$, the derivative of the numerator is $2xf(x^2)$ and the derivative of the denominator is $1$; so, since $f$ is continuous, it is $2xf(x^2) \to 2 \cdot 0 \cdot f(0^2)=0$ as $x \to 0$ and thus the limit is $0$. However, the hypotheses of Hôpital's rule must be verified.

One of them is show that the limit is in the inderminate form $0/0$: while it is intuitive that an integral with the same upper and lower bounds is $0$ if those bounds are real numbers, evaluating a limit by substitution, that is, writing the identity $\lim_{x \to 0} \int_0^{x^2} f(t)dt=\int_0^{0^2}f(t)dt$, needs that the integral function is continuous as a function of the upper bound of integration; I know that the integral functions are Lipschitz continuous (because, in the Riemann integral theory, we assume bounded integrand functions and from this it can be shown that the generic integral function $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $L=\sup (f)$), and so it is actually rigorous to evaluate the limit of the integral function by substituting the upper bound of integration, because Lipschitz continuous implies continuous and the composition of the integral function with $x^2$ is continuous as composition of continuous functions.

Moreover, it is rigorous to take the derivative of the integral function because, since by hypothesis $f$ is continuous, the fundamental theorem of calculus assures that the integral function is differentiable and its derivative, using the chain rule, is the integrand function evaluated in $x^2$ times the derivative of $x^2$, that is $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^{x^2} f(t)dt\right)=2xf(x^2)$.

Finally, Hopital's rule requires that the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2xf(x^2)}{1}$ exists, and this holds because since $f$ is continuous it is $2xf(x^2)$ has limit $2 \cdot 0 \cdot f(0^2)=0$.

Is all this reasoning correct to justify rigorously the use of Hôpital's rule in these kind of limits?

Comment: Your argument is correct, although you are overthinking  the whole thing. Since your assumption is that $f$ is continuous, all falls due to the humble chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus for Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Let $F(x)=\int_0^{x^2}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$. Then $F(0)=0$, and therefore, by definition, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac1x\int_0^{x^2}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is $F'(0)$, since it is the same thing as $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}x$. But, in order to apply L'Hopital's Rule, you must know what is $F'(x)$. In particular, you must already know that $F'(0)=0$. So there is a circular argument here, unless you say that you only used the fact that $F'(x)=2xf(x^2)$ when $x\ne0$. That's not convincing.

Comment: THe OP knows what $F'(x)$ is since $F(x)$ is the composition of $\phi:t\mapsto\int^t_0 f(s)\,dx$ and $g:x\mapsto x^2$, i.e. $F(x)=\phi(g(x))$ and he is using correctly the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Agree with all that and I fail to see how is that relevant to what I wrote.

Comment: The thing is that l'Hospital rule is not needed here as the whole thing can be reduced to the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus (for undergraduates)

Comment: Again, I agree. But the question was “Is all this reasoning correct to justify rigorously the use of Hôpital's rule in these kind of limits?” And what I did was to answer that question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your answer. I used only this: since I know that $F(x)=\int_0^{x^2} f(t)dt$ is differentiable for the FTOC and it is $F'(x)=2xf(x^2)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the limit is equal to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2xf(x^2)}{1}=\frac{0}{1}=0$. To be honest, I'm not sure if I have implicitly used $F'(0)=0$. Maybe you meant that I could say that the limit is equal to $\frac{F'(0)}{1}$ and use, without knowing it, $F'(0)=0$ to conclude that the latter fraction is $0$? If you meant this, no. I used $2xf(x^2)$. Knowing this, is my reasoning saved?

Comment: I agree that you did not the fact that $F'(0)=0$ in order prove that your limit is $0$. But you did use the fact that for every $x$ other than $0$ you do have $F'(x)=2xf(x^2)$. How can you prove that in a way that doesn't let you deduce right away that that equality also holds when $x=0$? So, while technically your proof can be seen as non-circular, I think that it is still rather artificial.